# focus() to input without scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have a search input text which I'd like to apply a `focus()` when loading the page, the problem is that the `focus` function automatically does a scroll to this field. Any solution to disable this scroll?

```
<input id="search_terms" type="text" />
<script>
    document.getelementbyId('search-terms').focus();
</script>
```

Comment: You want to capture your users' keystrokes *without* them seeing the element they're typing into?

Comment: Why do you consider this scrolling to be a problem?

Comment: You would have to set the scroll position using JavaScript after load: window.scrollTo(x,y)

Comment: I have an app which needs exactly this behaviour. I have a page which displays data from three consecutive months in a year. There are next and previous buttons which change which three months you view. 

When the user clicks next or previous I refocus the cursor on the last selected input, allowing users to keep track of their position (if they are entering data or checking figures).

In this case scrolling is really jarring, and stops you pressing the prev/next buttons repeatedly.

Comment: This just drove me absolutely nuts. Apparently there's an option you can pass to focus called preventScroll: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

Comment: Thanks, @BillCriswell - very grateful to you and Josh (below). I wasn't aware of `element.focus({preventScroll: true})` before and this has just saved me a lot of time and frustration.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Here's a complete solution:

```
var cursorFocus = function(elem) {
  var x = window.scrollX, y = window.scrollY;
  elem.focus();
  window.scrollTo(x, y);
}

cursorFocus(document.getElementById('search-terms'));
```

Comment: Good solution, however on some cases on IE9 it is better to use `setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(x, y); }, 100);` instead of `window.scrollTo(x, y);`.

Comment: window.scrollX and window.scrollY are not cross browser save, use document.body.scrollLeft and document.body.scrollTop

Comment: They work with most modern browsers (IE9+), I think that's reasonable.

Comment: When I do this, I can still see the page scroll to top and then jump back to the saved position. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Which browser are you using? It may animate the scroll before responding to programmatic events

Comment: simple solution for this will be elem.focus({preventScroll:false})

Answer (score 136):

There is a new [WHATWG standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#focus-management-apis) which allows you you to pass an object to `focus()` which specifies that you want to prevent the browser from scrolling the element into view:

```
const element = document.getElementById('search-terms')

element.focus({
  preventScroll: true
});
```

It has been supported since [Chrome 64](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745122025144320) and [Edge Insider Preview build 17046](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/14314565:), and should be landing in [Firefox 68](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1374045#c16) – a support matrix is available on [web-platform-tests here](https://wpt.fyi/results/html/interaction/focus/processing-model/preventScroll.html?label=master&product=chrome%5Bstable%5D&product=edge%5Bstable%5D&product=firefox%5Bexperimental%5D&product=safari%5Bexperimental%5D&aligned).

Comment: Yeah unfortunately it isn't production ready right now, but hopefully it will gain traction soon. I've [created a PR to add the relevant data to caniuse.com](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/pull/4035) which hopefully will track ongoing implementations.

Comment: Does anyone know of a polyfill for this behavior? I wasn't able to find one.

Comment: I find this to be not supported in Firefox but in Chrome. How on earth is that possible?

Comment: @Sunny relevant Mozilla bugs filed here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1374045 & https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1410112

Comment: Thanks! @YonaAppletree according to [webplatform.news](https://webplatform.news/issues/2019-04-19) there is a polyfill [available here](https://github.com/calvellido/focus-options-polyfill), however I haven't tested it.

Comment: it does not work in Chrome, it still scrolls :( looks like a Chrome bug

Answer (score 11):

If you are using jQuery, you can also do this:

```
$.fn.focusWithoutScrolling = function(){
  var x = window.scrollX, y = window.scrollY;
  this.focus();
  window.scrollTo(x, y);
};
```

and then

```
$('#search_terms').focusWithoutScrolling();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I found the need to change the first line of your function to `var x = $(document).scrollLeft(), y = $(document).scrollTop();` in order to get it working in IE10.

Answer (score 8):

The answers here do not take care of scrolling on the whole hierarchy, but the main scrollbars only. This answer will take care of everything:

```
    var focusWithoutScrolling = function (el) {
        var scrollHierarchy = [];

        var parent = el.parentNode;
        while (parent) {
            scrollHierarchy.push([parent, parent.scrollLeft, parent.scrollTop]);
            parent = parent.parentNode;
        }

        el.focus();

        scrollHierarchy.forEach(function (item) {
            var el = item[0];

            // Check first to avoid triggering unnecessary `scroll` events

            if (el.scrollLeft != item[1])
                el.scrollLeft = item[1];

            if (el.scrollTop != item[2])
                el.scrollTop = item[2];
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 6):

A bit modified version that supports more browsers (incl. IE9)

```
var cursorFocus = function(elem) {
  var x, y;
  // More sources for scroll x, y offset.
  if (typeof(window.pageXOffset) !== 'undefined') {
      x = window.pageXOffset;
      y = window.pageYOffset;
  } else if (typeof(window.scrollX) !== 'undefined') {
      x = window.scrollX;
      y = window.scrollY;
  } else if (document.documentElement && typeof(document.documentElement.scrollLeft) !== 'undefined') {
      x = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      y = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  } else {
      x = document.body.scrollLeft;
      y = document.body.scrollTop;
  }

  elem.focus();

  if (typeof x !== 'undefined') {
      // In some cases IE9 does not seem to catch instant scrollTo request.
      setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(x, y); }, 100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that was driving me crazy. Using jQuery, I've found a solution by discovering the coordinates of mouse and input and then scrolling to the difference between them. In your case it could be something like this:

```
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    mouseCoords = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };
  });

  $('#search_terms').bind("focus", function (e) {
      var offset = e.offset();
      window.scrollTo(
        offset.left - mouseCoords.x,
        offset.top - mouseCoords.y
      );
  });
```

Answer (score -4):

As of today, the preferred way to set the focus on an element upon page load is using the `autofocus` attribute. This does not involve any scrolling.

```html
<input id="search_terms" type="text" autofocus />
```

The `autofocus` attrubute [is part of the HTML5 standard](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#attr-fe-autofocus) and is supported by all major browsers, with the only notable exception of Internet Explorer 9 or earlier.

Comment: I am glad to see this modern approach to focusing an input but it does still "scroll" to the focused input box(at least in Chrome). For instance, when you refresh a page in Chrome it reloads the page but leaves you scrolled to same part on that page. If you set autofocus on an input halfway down the page, when you reload you will now be scrolled to have the input vertically centered. I think this "scroll" is what the OP is trying to avoid. If the user is reading a long article we don't want them to be scrolled all the way to the search box at the top when they hit refresh.