# Prevent scrolling to input box when Javascript Focus is used

Tags: javascript

I would like the cursor to be automatically placed in a textbox when my page loads. However, I do not want the page to scroll down to this textbox (I would prefer that it remains out of view at the bottom of the page). This probably sounds odd, but I do have a need for it!

I make the cursor appear using this code:

```
<script>document.getElementById('textbox1').focus()</script>
```

Is anyone able to modify this code such that scrolling will not occur?

Comment: possible duplicate of [focus() to input without scolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963053/focus-to-input-without-scolling)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [focus() to input without scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963053/focus-to-input-without-scrolling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window object supports a scrollTo() method try adding it after focus()

```
document.getElementById('textbox1').focus(); window.scrollTo(0,0);
```