# Set textbox active without using focus()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, iframe

I have small iframe . The content of the iframe is larger than the iframe window and can be seen by scrolling around. There is a button in the iframe. Clicking that button animates for one second and increases height and width of iframe, loads a form and sets a text box as focus.

```
 $input[0].focus();
```

However, before the animation starts, the focus() is making the text box the center of the iframe window and distorting what is visible in the iframe window. 
How can I achieve this : The cursor to be active in that text box but not have the content of the iframe to be re-positioned. The re-positioning happens so that the text-box can be in visible part of iframe.

I cannot put focus() in the callback for animate() due to other constraints.

Comment: What constraints prevent you from putting it in the complete callback?

Comment: WOuld that work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963053/focus-to-input-without-scolling

Comment: @PatrickEvans The animate function is part of a client side code while the content of the iframe is being loaded by a server side code. I want to minimize the interaction between them.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Zyga, this worked :

```
function focusWithoutScrolling (element){
var x = window.scrollX, y = window.scrollY;
element.focus();
window.scrollTo(x,y);
```