# auto jump in javascript, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a project. You as a user are able to "add" input fields, however if you add too many input fields you will (of course) get a scrollbar.

It would be quite annoying to scroll all the way down to write something in an input field that's somewhere all the way down.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DanDy/esnq0qeh/) so you get a better idea of what I mean.

At first I thought maybe this could be done with autofocus, but (as far as I know) autofocus only focusses the input field.

I have been looking around and even read the API of javascript (in hopes of maybe encountering something similar would pop up), but I didn't find any.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = 0;
  var addOpdracht = $('<a/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-success',
    'id': 'addOpdracht'
  }).on('click', function() {
    $('form').append(getExerciseBlock(id));
    id++;
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>');

  $('form').append(addOpdracht);
  $('form').append(getExerciseTitle());
})



function getAddBtn(target, i) {
  var addBtn = $('<a/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-primary',
    'id': 'addBtn'
  }).on('click', function() {
    $(target).append(getWordPartInput(i));
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');
  console.log(target);
  return addBtn;
}

function getRemoveBtn(target, i) {
  var RemoveBtn = $('<a/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-danger'
  }).on('click', function() {
    let syllableInputs = $(this).parent().children("input.syllable");
    syllableInputs[syllableInputs.length - 1].remove(target);
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>');

  return RemoveBtn;
}



function getExerciseBlock(i) {
  var eBlock = $('<div/>', {
    'id': i,
    'class': 'col-md-12 eBlock'
  });

  $(eBlock).append(getAudioBtn(i), getWordInput(i), getWordPartInput(i), getWordPartInput(i), getRemoveBtn(i), getAddBtn(eBlock, i));

  return eBlock;
}


function getAudioBtn(id, cValue) {
  cValue = cValue || '';
  var audioBtn = $('<a/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-primary'
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>');
  return audioBtn;
}


function getWordInput(id, cValue) {
  cValue = cValue || '';
  var wInput = $('<input/>', {
    'class': 'exerciseGetWordInput form-group form-control',
    'type': 'text',
    'name': 'question_takeAudio_exerciseWord[]',
    'placeholder': 'Exercise',
    'id': 'exerciseGetWordInput'
    //'value': ' + response.main_object.exercises[i].exerciseGetWordInput + '
  })
  return wInput;
}


function getWordPartInput(id, cValue) {
  cValue = cValue || '';
  var wpInput = $('<input/>', {
    'class': 'form-group form-control syllable',
    'type': 'text',
    'value': cValue,
    'placeholder': 'Syllables',
    'id': 'SyllablesGetWordPartInput'
  });
  return wpInput;
}

function getExerciseTitle() {
  var exerciseTitle = $('<input/>', {
    'class': 'getExerciseTitle form-group form-control required',
    'type': 'text',
    'name': 'getExerciseTitle',
    'id': 'getExerciseTitle',
    'placeholder': 'Exercise title',
    'required': true
  });

  return exerciseTitle;
}


function getResetInputs() {
  location.reload();
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="row">
            <h2 id="exerciseTitleCMS" class="col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-6">Content Managment System</h2>
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-2">
              <h2>
                <select class="languageSelector form-control required" id="languageSelector"></select>
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="jumbotron" id="mainList">
            <form id='my_form' class="container-fluid" action="#" method="POST" required>
              <button id='resetInputs' type='button' onclick='getResetInputs()' class='btn btn-danger fa fa-refresh fa-2x resetInputs'></button>
              <button type='submit' id='saveBtn' class='btn btn-info fa fa-download fa-2x saveBtn' required></button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to know:
Is there a certain keyword that makes the autofocus (or in my case, the jump to the last added element) and if so, how should this be implemented?
EDIT: my "exercise input field" should be focussed only, not the syllables... And when I click the add button to add a new block (in the fiddle click the big + sign next to the download button), it stops focussing the new added element. Therefore I don't exactly think this is a duplicate of the question asked, he only needs one autofocus and that's it. I need mine to be focussed on the new added input element.

Comment: Focusing a field usually scrolls the page so that the field becomes visible if it wasn’t already ...

Comment: the fields are visible, but let's say (u can try it urself in the fiddle to get a better feel of what I mean) you add 100 input fields, it's quite annoying as user to click "add" and then to scroll ALL the way down to the input u just added. I want to click "add" and then have my page jump to the new added element (in this case it's an input field)

Comment: This is more of a ux/ui question than a coding question. But it would seem to make more sense to put the add button where the user expects the thing to be added, which means you won't have this scrolling issue.

Comment: @MattWay I wasn't sure if I was allowed to post something without coding (as it has no solution and stackoverflow demands one). besides, when I gave the SAME SOLUTION as u did to the person who was complaining about it, he neglected it and told me he wanted it like this and in no other way. I wouldn't have made this post if it wasn't for the old grandpa complaining about some common logic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [focus() to input without scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963053/focus-to-input-without-scrolling)

Comment: @Userwithnoname Name-calling is almost never the best approach. Us "old grandpas" built the stuff you're using today.

Comment: the "old grandpa" im refering to isn't even a programmer. Not only isn't he a programmer, he is LITTERLY AN OLD GRANDPA. so it isn't name-calling when I am describing the person. Since he isn't a programmer either, I think I can say for certain that he didn't built the stuff i'm using today :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is fiddle for what you want [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yunus_aslam/esnq0qeh/3/)

You will notice that I have added the focus and select function in the click even

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = 0;
  var addOpdracht = $('<a/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-success',
    'id': 'addOpdracht'
  }).on('click', function() {
    $('form').append(getExerciseBlock(id));
    $(".exerciseGetWordInput_" + id).focus().select(); /// I also changed the class a little to make it unique
    id++;
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>');

  $('form').append(addOpdracht);
  $('form').append(getExerciseTitle());
});
```

In the function

```
function getWordInput(id, cValue) {
  cValue = cValue || '';
  var wInput = $('<input/>', {
    'class': 'exerciseGetWordInput_' + id + ' form-group form-control',  // changed the class name here
    'type': 'text',
    'name': 'question_takeAudio_exerciseWord[]',
    'placeholder': 'Exercise',
    'id': 'exerciseGetWordInput'
  })
  return wInput;
}
```

See how I have added the unique class name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Bro, everybody tried to help you. Don't call it dog shit. Your code has one more issue which they are trying to show you. The Ids are same for every element which it should never be. So in the way I have changed the class name for every new generated element also change the ID.

Comment: You are right, my apologies, I have been working on for a few hours now, the slightest displeasing comment made me go off. I appreciate the help everyone put into this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963053/focus-to-input-without-scrolling) is how you can do this.

> Here's a complete solution:
>
> ```
> var cursorFocus = function(elem) {
>     var x = window.scrollX, y = window.scrollY;
>     elem.focus();
>     window.scrollTo(x, y);
> }
>
> cursorFocus(document.getElementById('search-terms'));
> ```

The principle is quite simple. Except of focusing you need to scroll to that element.

**EDIT**

For OP:
[image]

There are many elements with the same id, so don't say there are not.

This is not the way to go.

Anyway after you create input (on plus icon click) you should give it an unique id or class and then you can use the solution above using function like this

```
cursorFocus(document.getElementById('your_unique_id'));
```

or

```
cursorFocus(document.getElementsByClassName('your_unique_classname')[0]);
```

**EDIT2**

It was just qoutation, it wasn't my solution. But here is a quick fix.

Instead of

```
var x = window.scrollX, y = window.scrollY;
```

Do

```
var x = elem.scrollX, y = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;
```

Comment: No, this didn't work (or I am doing it wrong?) my input fields, as u can see, are duplicates when clicked on the "add" button. It only focusses the first one, but after that it doesn't focus the new added element

Comment: From what i understood this code does the contrary of what the OP wants (see his first comment). This would actually prevent from scrolling to the added element when he focuses it.

Comment: @Kaddath Not true, this function scrolls the page to given element.  Userwithnoname: This is highly inappropriate way to go. You should not create mpore than one element with the same id. You should add class with next number and refer to that class, so my solution is correct.

Comment: "So my solution is correct", no not really. the BLOCKS have DIFFERENT IDS, they will be stored in the database with the IDS they are given. the input field ur speaking of is one, so there is only one ID in that page and not more. Besides, they have a class too. So ur comment would still be invalid. since i'm refering to the function anyway and not to a specific ID to duplicate. and the BLOCKS it makes (which are stored by ID in a DB have different IDS as they count up.

Comment: @Userwithnoname look at edit I did and don't lie to me. Jeez man, I'm trying to help you. What gives?

Comment: well, that's the result i have, as expected. It prevents from scrolling to the focused input. Not surprising because you yook it from "focus() to input **without** scrolling": [see the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1u4f2eoc/). Remove the `window.scrollTo` line and it will scroll automatically

Comment: Thank you all for the input, time and effort. I found what I Was looking for and i'm sorry if I came across as a special need kid. I appreciate the effort a lot. Thank you all and peace.