# Orange color at default active button

Tags: css

I have 3 buttons and when i click on each button, the active button has orange collor (:focus on css, its working), but when i load the page, i want to set the first button as a default active button (so it color is orange). How to do this? My code is:

HTML:

```
 <div class="tabs">
                <a class="btn black" rel="0" tabindex="1">1 button</a>
                <a class="btn black" rel="1" tabindex="1">2 button</a>
                <a class="btn black" rel="2" tabindex="1">3 button</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .btn {height:42px;}
  .btn.black:focus {background:#ff6600;}
  .btn.black:active {background:#ff6600;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set focus on that element using `focus()` method

```css
.btn {
  height: 42px;
}

.btn.black:focus {
  background: #ff6600;
}

.btn.black:active {
  background: #ff6600;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <a id="abc" class="btn black" rel="0" tabindex="1">1 button</a>
  <a class="btn black" rel="1" tabindex="1">2 button</a>
  <a class="btn black" rel="2" tabindex="1">3 button</a>
</div>

<script>
  document.getElementById("abc").focus()
</script>
```

```css
.btn {
  height: 42px;
}

.btn.black:focus {
  background: #ff6600;
}

.btn.black:active {
  background: #ff6600;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some
  content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content
  Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some
  content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content
  Some content
</div>
<div class="tabs">
  <a id="abc" class="btn black" rel="0" tabindex="1">1 button</a>
  <a class="btn black" rel="1" tabindex="1">2 button</a>
  <a class="btn black" rel="2" tabindex="1">3 button</a>
</div>

<script>
  var cursorFocus = function(elem) {
    var x = window.scrollX,
      y = window.scrollY;
    elem.focus();
    window.scrollTo(x, y);
  }

  cursorFocus(document.getElementById('abc'));
</script>
```

Comment: You are welccome @MarcelinoPietero  :)

Comment: I'd imagine because you used JS when it was flagged as a CSS question, but as that's not possible in pure CSS, have my upvote to restore the balance ;)

Comment: Hahaha.. May be ... Thanks :)

Comment: Hello, i have problem with this. When i use it, its working fine, but when i refresh or access the page its scroll me automatically to that section where is this element. Not to the top of page (like classic).

Comment: ok marciello, will look into it and let you know in an hour or so. Not on my pc right now

Comment: Try this solution  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963053/focus-to-input-without-scrolling

Comment: @MarcelinoPietero Check the second snippet i added

Comment: I add that cursorFocus after my adc.focus() but its not working.. it always scroll me down to that element.

Comment: Check my second snippet. For some reason my updated answer was not showing, now i have added it again,

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5, you can use `autofocus`, but you'll need to switch from `<a>` to `<button>` elements:

```
<div class="tabs">
   <button class="btn black" rel="0" tabindex="1" autofocus>1 button</button>
   <button class="btn black" rel="1" tabindex="1">2 button</button>
   <button class="btn black" rel="2" tabindex="1">3 button</button>
</div>
```

no JavaScript required :)

edit:
[Link to the autofocus documentation](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control)

Comment: Its not working! I tried that. I think it only works for input type elements

Comment: do your links need to be links, or can you switch to the <button> element instead? If you do, autofocus will work.

Comment: Hello, i have problem with this. When i use it, its working fine, but when i refresh or access the page its scroll me automatically to that section where is this element. Not to the top of page (like classic).

Answer (score 0):

if you use **button** instead of **anchor** then you can use **autofocus** like the following

```
<div class="tabs">
    <button type="button" class="btn black" rel="0" autofocus>1 button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn black" rel="1" tabindex="1">2 button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn black" rel="2" tabindex="1">3 button</button>
</div>
```