# How to insert a number directally in a input through a keypad in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, numpad, numeric-keypad

I am a little confused about [this plugin](https://a.kabachnik.info/jquery-numpad.html). Is there a way to insert the numbers directly in my `text-basic` input instead of to press "Done" in keypad? I'd like that as I type the numbers in keypad they be shown automatically in `text-basic` input (because until now it's necessary to preview in keypad input and to press enter to make they be shown).

Here is the code:

```js
/**
 * jQuery.NumPad
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2015 Andrej Kabachnik
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Project home:
 * https://github.com/kabachello/jQuery.NumPad
 *
 * Version: 1.4
 *
 */
(function($){

 // From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963053/focus-to-input-without-scrolling
 var cursorFocus = function(elem) {
  var x = window.scrollX, y = window.scrollY;
  elem.focus();
  window.scrollTo(x, y);
 }
 
    $.fn.numpad=function(options){
     
     if (typeof options == 'string'){
      var nmpd = $.data(this[0], 'numpad');
      if (!nmpd) throw "Cannot perform '" + options + "' on a numpad prior to initialization!";
      switch (options){
       case 'open': 
        nmpd.open(nmpd.options.target ? nmpd.options.target : this.first());
        break;
       case 'close':
        nmpd.open(nmpd.options.target ? nmpd.options.target : this.first());
        break;
      }
      return this;
     } 
     
  // Apply the specified options overriding the defaults
  options = $.extend({}, $.fn.numpad.defaults, options);
  
  // Create a numpad. One for all elements in this jQuery selector.
  // Since numpad() can be called on multiple elements on one page, each call will create a unique numpad id.
  var id = 'nmpd' + ($('.nmpd-wrapper').length + 1);
  var nmpd = {};
  return this.each(function(){
   
   // If an element with the generated unique numpad id exists, the numpad had been instantiated already.
   // Otherwise create a new one!
   if ($('#'+id).length == 0) {
    /** @var nmpd jQuery object containing the entire numpad */
    nmpd = $('<div id="' + id + '"></div>').addClass('nmpd-wrapper');
    nmpd.options = options;
    /** @var display jQuery object representing the display of the numpad (typically an input field) */
    var display = $(options.displayTpl).addClass('nmpd-display');
    nmpd.display = display;
    /** @var grid jQuery object containing the grid for the numpad: the display, the buttons, etc. */
    var table = $(options.gridTpl).addClass('nmpd-grid');
    nmpd.grid = table;
    table.append($(options.rowTpl).append($(options.displayCellTpl).append(display).append($('<input type="hidden" class="dirty" value="0"></input>'))));
    // Create rows and columns of the the grid with appropriate buttons
    table.append(
     $(options.rowTpl)
      .append($(options.cellTpl).append($(options.buttonNumberTpl).html(7).addClass('numero')))
      .append($(options.cellTpl).append($(options.buttonNumberTpl).html(8).addClass('numero')))
      .append($(options.cellTpl).append($(options.buttonNumberTpl).html(9).addClass('numero')))
      .append($(options.cellTpl).append($(options.buttonFunctionTpl).html(options.textDelete).addClass('del').click(function(){
       nmpd.setValue(nmpd.getValue().toString().substring(0,nmpd.getValue().toString().length - 1));
      })))
     ).append(
     $(options.rowTpl)
      .append($(options.cellTpl).append($(options.buttonNumberTpl).html(4).addClass('numero')))
      .append($(options.cellTpl).append($(options.buttonNumberTpl).html(5).addClass('numero')))
      .append($(options.cellTpl).append($(options.buttonNumberTpl).html(6).addClass('numero')))
      .append($(options.cellTpl).append($(options.buttonFunctionTpl).html(options.textClear).addClass('clear').click(function(){
       nmpd.setValue('');
      })))
     ).append(
     $(options.rowTpl)
      .append($(options.cellTpl).append($(options.buttonNumberTpl).html(1).addClass('numero')))
      .append($(options.cellTpl).append($(options.buttonNumberTpl).html(2).addClass('numero')))
      .append($(options.cellTpl).append($(options.buttonNumberTpl).html(3).addClass('numero')))
      .append($(options.cellTpl).append($(options.buttonFunctionTpl).html(options.textCancel).addClass('cancel').click(function(){
       nmpd.close(false);
      })))
     ).append(
     $(options.rowTpl)
      .append($(options.cellTpl).append($(options.buttonFunctionTpl).html('&plusmn;').addClass('neg').click(function(){
       nmpd.setValue(nmpd.getValue() * (-1));
      })))
      .append($(options.cellTpl).append($(options.buttonNumberTpl).html(0).addClass('numero')))
      .append($(options.cellTpl).append($(options.buttonFunctionTpl).html(options.decimalSeparator).addClass('sep').click(function(){
       nmpd.setValue(nmpd.getValue().toString() + options.decimalSeparator);
      })))
      .append($(options.cellTpl).append($(options.buttonFunctionTpl).html(options.textDone).addClass('done')))
     );
    // Create the backdrop of the numpad - an overlay for the main page
    nmpd.append($(options.backgroundTpl).addClass('nmpd-overlay').click(function(){nmpd.close(false);}));
    // Append the grid table to the nmpd element
    nmpd.append(table);
    
    // Hide buttons to be hidden
    if (options.hidePlusMinusButton){
     nmpd.find('.neg').hide();
    }
    if (options.hideDecimalButton){
     nmpd.find('.sep').hide();
    }
    
    // Attach events
    if (options.onKeypadCreate){
     nmpd.on('numpad.create', options.onKeypadCreate);
    }
    if (options.onKeypadOpen){
     nmpd.on('numpad.open', options.onKeypadOpen);
    }
    if (options.onKeypadClose){
     nmpd.on('numpad.close', options.onKeypadClose);
    }
    if (options.onChange){
     nmpd.on('numpad.change', options.onChange);
    }
    (options.appendKeypadTo ? options.appendKeypadTo : $(document.body)).append(nmpd);   
    
    // Special event for the numeric buttons
    $('#'+id+' .numero').bind('click', function(){
     var val;
     if ($('#'+id+' .dirty').val() == '0'){
      val = $(this).text();
     } else {
      val = nmpd.getValue() ? nmpd.getValue().toString() + $(this).text() : $(this).text();
     }
     nmpd.setValue(val); 
    });
    
    // Finally, once the numpad is completely instantiated, trigger numpad.create
    nmpd.trigger('numpad.create');
   } else {
    // If the numpad was already instantiated previously, just load it into the nmpd variable
    //nmpd = $('#'+id);
    //nmpd.display = $('#'+id+' input.nmpd-display'); 
   }
   
   $.data(this, 'numpad', nmpd);
   
   // Make the target element readonly and save the numpad id in the data-numpad property. Also add the special nmpd-target CSS class.
   $(this).attr("readonly", true).attr('data-numpad', id).addClass('nmpd-target');
   
   // Register a listener to open the numpad on the event specified in the options
   $(this).bind(options.openOnEvent,function(){
    nmpd.open(options.target ? options.target : $(this));
   });
   
   // Define helper functions
   
   /**
   * Gets the current value displayed in the numpad
   * @return string | number
   */
   nmpd.getValue = function(){
    return isNaN(nmpd.display.val()) ? 0 : nmpd.display.val();
   };
   
   /**
   * Sets the display value of the numpad
   * @param string value
   * @return jQuery object nmpd
   */
   nmpd.setValue = function(value){
    if (nmpd.display.attr('maxLength') < value.toString().length) value = value.toString().substr(0, nmpd.display.attr('maxLength'));
    nmpd.display.val(value);
    nmpd.find('.dirty').val('1');
    nmpd.trigger('numpad.change', [value]);
    return nmpd;
   };
   
   /**
   * Closes the numpad writing it's value to the given target element
   * @param jQuery object target
   * @return jQuery object nmpd
   */
   nmpd.close = function(target){
    // If a target element is given, set it's value to the dipslay value of the numpad. Otherwise just hide the numpad
    if (target){
     if (target.prop("tagName") == 'INPUT'){
      target.val(nmpd.getValue().toString().replace('.', options.decimalSeparator));
     } else {
      target.html(nmpd.getValue().toString().replace('.', options.decimalSeparator));
     }
    } 
    // Hide the numpad and trigger numpad.close
    nmpd.hide();
    nmpd.trigger('numpad.close');
    // Trigger a change event on the target element if the value has really been changed
    // TODO check if the value has really been changed!
    if (target && target.prop("tagName") == 'INPUT'){
     target.trigger('change');
    }
    return nmpd;
   };
   
   /**
   * Opens the numpad for a given target element optionally filling it with a given value
   * @param jQuery object target
   * @param string initialValue
   * @return jQuery object nmpd
   */
   nmpd.open = function(target, initialValue){
    // Set the initial value
    // Use nmpd.display.val to avoid triggering numpad.change for the initial value
    if (initialValue){
     nmpd.display.val(initialValue);
    } else {
     if (target.prop("tagName") == 'INPUT'){
      nmpd.display.val(target.val());
      nmpd.display.attr('maxLength', target.attr('maxLength'));
     } else {
      nmpd.display.val(parseFloat(target.text()));
     }
    }
    // Mark the numpad as not dirty initially
    $('#'+id+' .dirty').val(0);
    // Show the numpad and position it on the page
    cursorFocus(nmpd.show().find('.cancel'));
    position(nmpd.find('.nmpd-grid'), options.position, options.positionX, options.positionY);
    // Register a click handler on the done button to update the target element
    // Make sure all other click handlers get removed. Otherwise some unwanted sideeffects may occur if the numpad is
    // opened multiple times for some reason
    $('#'+id+' .done').off('click');
    $('#'+id+' .done').one('click', function(){ nmpd.close(target); });
    // Finally trigger numpad.open
    nmpd.trigger('numpad.open');
    return nmpd;
   };    
  });
    };
    
 /**
 * Positions any given jQuery element within the page
 */
    function position(element, mode, posX, posY) {
     var x = 0;
     var y = 0;
     if (mode == 'fixed'){
         element.css('position','fixed');
         
         if (posX == 'left'){
          x = 0;
         } else if (posX == 'right'){
          x = $(window).width() - element.outerWidth();
         } else if (posX == 'center'){
          x = ($(window).width() / 2) - (element.outerWidth() / 2);
         } else if ($.type(posX) == 'number'){
          x = posX;
         }
         element.css('left', x);
                  
         if (posY == 'top'){
          y = 0;
         } else if (posY == 'bottom'){
          y = $(window).height() - element.outerHeight();
         } else if (posY == 'middle'){
          y = ($(window).height() / 2) - (element.outerHeight() / 2);
         } else if ($.type(posY) == 'number'){
          y = posY;
         }
         element.css('top', y);
     }
        return element;
    }
 
 // Default values for numpad options
 $.fn.numpad.defaults = {
  target: false,
  openOnEvent: 'click',
  backgroundTpl: '<div></div>',
  gridTpl: '<table></table>',
  displayTpl: '<input type="text" />',
  displayCellTpl: '<td colspan="4"></td>',
  rowTpl: '<tr></tr>',
  cellTpl: '<td></td>',
  buttonNumberTpl: '<button></button>',
  buttonFunctionTpl: '<button></button>',
  gridTableClass: '',
  hidePlusMinusButton: false,
  hideDecimalButton: false,
  textDone: 'Done',
  textDelete: 'Del',
  textClear: 'Clear',
  textCancel: 'Cancel',
  decimalSeparator: ',',
  precision: null,
  appendKeypadTo: false,
  position: 'fixed',
  positionX: 'center',
  positionY: 'middle',
  onKeypadCreate: false,
  onKeypadOpen: false,
  onKeypadClose: false,
  onChange: false
 };
})(jQuery);

$('#text-basic').numpad();
```

```css
.nmpd-wrapper {display: none;}
.nmpd-target {cursor: pointer;}
.nmpd-grid {position:absolute; left:50px; top:50px; z-index:5000; -khtml-user-select: none; border-radius:10px; padding:10px; width: initial;}
.nmpd-overlay {z-index:4999;}
input.nmpd-display {text-align: right;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="text-basic" placeholder="Click to show numpad">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[ UPDATE ]**

You just need to add this option to the initialization. No need to edit the plugin code:

```
$('#text-basic').numpad({
  onChange: (e,value)=>$("#text-basic").val( value )
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @KostasX It helped me a lot! God bless you, man!

Comment: Just updated the answer. No need to touch the plugin code.